# How can I invoke ProGuard, with optimization only settings, even for ant debug builds?

Tags: android, optimization, ant, proguard, build.xml

I want to use ProGruad's for my open source Android app when creating a debug apk with `ant debug`. I only use ProGuard's optimizations and do not use any code obfuscation settings, i.e.  basically the ProGuard configuration from `$ANDROID_HOME/tools/proguard/proguard-android-optimize.txt`.

But the ProGuard invokation, which is done withing the `-obfuscate` task in Android's `build.xml`, is disabled by the `debug` target. How can I enable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to configure Android ant build system to invoke proguard even with `debug` builds, the two variables need to be set: `proguard.enabled` and `out.dex.jar.input.ref`.

Here is the example configuration. Put the `custom_rules.xml` file directly in your projects root.

**custom_rules.xml**

```
<project name="android_rules" default="debug">
  <!-- Zap debug-obfuscation-check from SDK's build.xml so that it
       can't set proguard.enabled to false !-->
  <target name="-debug-obfuscation-check"/>
  <target name="-pre-build">
    <condition property="proguard.enabled" value="true" else="false">
      <isset property="proguard.config" />
    </condition>
    <if condition="${proguard.enabled}">
      <then>
    <echo level="info">Proguard.config is enabled</echo>
    <!-- Secondary dx input (jar files) is empty since all the
             jar files will be in the obfuscated jar -->
    <path id="out.dex.jar.input.ref" />
      </then>
      <else>
    <echo level="info">Proguard.config is disabled</echo>
      </else>
    </if>
  </target>
</project>
```